# Can you encrypt a hard disk with gpg?

Tags: encryption, gnupg

Can you encrypt a hard disk with gpg? Is there ***any*** tool to do that?

Comment: Most OS'ses allow you to access a HDD as a file. So technically it is possible.  I suspect that it will not do what you want though.

Comment: Why do you want to do that? What is your use case?

Comment: The commercial PGP used to have "PGP Disk".

Answer (score 4):

You can do this using [GPG encrypted loopback disks](http://patrick.uiterwijk.org/2013/02/25/gpg-encrypted-loopback-disks/). This page explains the concept like so:

> My intention was to be able to secure some data by encrypting them
>   with a GPG key, but not have to create a new partition on my disk.
>   Also, I wanted to do easy backups by just backing up a single file. I
>   also wanted to be sure that I would still be able to recover
>   everything in case my disk encryption GPG key was lost. Since I am not
>   aware of any systems that do this automatically, I just combined
>   loopback devices, luks and GPG into a set of bash scripts.

Answer (score 2):

Even if it's possible, it probably isn't a good solution because disk encryption needs to be a transparent layer between OS and disk due to the continuous I/O.

Comment: It's certainly much more practical than encrypting each and every file individually and has the same performance.